# How to find the time interval between two unix timestamps?

Tags: python, numpy, time

I want to check if the time difference between two unix timestamps is close to a given interval and print the timestamp and use this new timestamp to compare further timestamps to see if the difference is close to the interval. The timestamps are in a numpy array.

This is my try at this:

```py
from math import isclose
def check_time_interval(now, update, interval):
    if isclose(update - now, interval):
        # do something
        print(update)
        return update
    else:
        return now

interval = 60.0

now = timestamps[0]
for timestamp in timestamps:
    now = check_time_interval(now, timestamp, interval)
```

This code doesn't print any timestamps although the difference is close to the interval. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better and efficient way to do this?

Edit:

sample input:

```
timestamps = [1632267861.212 + i for i in range(100)]
```

Comment: You us a sample input and output!

Comment: added a sample input. sample output would be `1632267921.212`

Answer (score 0):

You use `isclose` incorrectly. Try this:

```
from math import isclose
def check_time_interval(now, update, interval):
    if isclose(update, now, abs_tol=interval):
        # do something
        print(update)
        return update
    else:
        return now

interval = 60.0
timestamps = [1632267861.212 + i for i in range(100)]

now = timestamps[0]
for timestamp in timestamps:
    check_time_interval(now, timestamp, interval)
```

As for more efficient way, you could vectorize and check all intervals using numpy, something like this:

```
import numpy as np
timestamps = np.array(timestamps)
is_close = np.abs(timestamps - now) <= 60
print(timestamps[is_close])
```

Comment: This just prints all the input timestamps. Not what I wanted.

Comment: hmm, but numpy method works. I do not understand why `isclose` is still not working properly

Comment: Ok, I see, you overwrite `now` in the for loop. Thats the reason

Comment: @papbiceps I edited answer, now should work as intended I hope?